# Ant design react multiple form layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want my form to have a vertical layout and a portion of my form I want to have an inline form. How to achieve this? I see no docs.

Comment: any own attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this using `flex` and some CSS tweaks.

Add a wrapper around your inline part with `display: flex` and also force `display: flex` to the children of your wrapper.

https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-swartz-4vfp2

Another solution is to just combine inline parts together. Choose an inline layout for your form and just add `<br/>` where you want line breaks.